# Dynamic Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a situation where I am trying to create a update / delete panel.  I currently have worked in the delete panel and decided I wanted to use the same controls for the update panel. The only way I can see this working is if the confirmation button can pick up which button was pressed.  I can not seem to figure out how to do this.  Is there a way to do this without creating a whole new popup menu with different set of buttons and all?

// Note that this is unfinished code and I am still experimenting with the code, so if anything is not clear to you just ask and I will try to explain.

javascript

```
//execute popup
function popup() {
    $("#popupbg").animate({ opacity: ".8" });
    $("#delete, #update").click(
    function() {
        $("#popupbg, #popupbgitembg").show('fast')
    });
}
//execute popup cancel
function popupcancel() {
     $("#popupbg, #popupbgitembg").hide('medium');
}
//execute popup delete
    function popupdel() {
        $('execdelete').click();
            var button = document.getElementById("<%= execdelete.ClientID %>");
            button.click();
        $("#popupbg, #popupbgitembg").hide('medium');
    }
```

HTML (popupbg is the background)

```
<div id="popupbg"> 
</div> 
<div id="popupbgitembg">
<ul class="popupbgitems">
        <li id="lidelete" visible="false">
            <asp:Label ID="lblpopup" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            Are you sure you want to delete?
        </li> 
        <li></li> 
        <li>
            <asp:Button ID="execdelete" runat="server" CssClass="invisible" OnClick="delSysGLDepts" />
            <asp:Button ID="execupdate" runat="server" CssClass="invisible" OnClick="updateSysGLDepts" />
            <asp:Button ID="butdelete" runat="server" Text="Yes" Width="70px" OnClientClick="javascript:scroll;popupdel();" Font-Size="11.5px"/>
            <asp:Button ID="butcancel" runat="server" Text="No" Width="70px" OnClientClick="javascript:popupcancel();" Font-Size="11.5px"/>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>    

<li><asp:Button ID="update" Text="Update" style="font-size:11px"  runat="server"/>
                        <asp:Button ID="delete" Text="Delete" style="font-size:11px" OnClientClick="javascript:popup('delete');" runat="server"/>

                   </li>
```

Comment: Is there something specifically bad about creating more than one popup that you are trying to avoid? If the popup is a simple ok/cancel dialog, I would think that it would be easier to have 2 simple popups than 1 dynamic popup.

Comment: Besides adding an exact copy of everything above, No I do not think there is. Just wanted to know if there was a way to do it so that the code could sit cleaner (It is going to be the same for the create function also) and not be an extra 100 lines where the only thing changed is one says update/ create and another says delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part

```
$("#delete, #update").click(
    function() {
        $("#popupbg, #popupbgitembg").show('fast')
    });
```

is the click action for your delete and update buttons. In your click function, you can do

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
if (id == "delete") {
   //setup the form for delete - show or hide delete stuff
} else if (id =="update") {
   //setup the form for update - show or hide update stuff
}
```

On your popup, you can have one button that does the update, and another that does the delete. In your setup code, show the one you want and hide the other one. Same with any text.